# mod_deflate compression causing swf files to not work correctly

Tags: .htaccess, compression, flash, mod-deflate

Recently enabled `mod_defalte` on my server to compress certain files.

I thought the setup wouldn't cause any issues with `.swf` files but ever since I've had issues relating to `.swf` files running but not getting past their loading screens.

**mod_deflate directory htaccess config**

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/text text/html text/plain text/xml text/css application/x-javascript application/javascript
</ifmodule>
```

I've noticed there seems to be quite a few issues relating to compression and `.swf` files  but I'm unsure why `mod_deflate` would be affecting them when it's set to run as above?

**Possible Cause?**

I do have the following settings below in WHM -> Apache Configuration -> Include Editor, are these the default `mod_deflate` settings or something I've added in?

I only want to do a basic config as in the above example, should I just delete the `post_virtualhost_global.conf` settings?

**mod_deflate - post_virtualhost_global.conf**

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
# Netscape 4.x has some problems…
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html

# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip

# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
# BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# NOTE: Due to a bug in mod_setenvif up to Apache 2.0.48
# the above regex won’t work. You can use the following
# workaround to get the desired effect:
BrowserMatch \bMSI[E] !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

# Don’t compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI .(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
# Make sure proxies don’t deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

---

*Source*

mod_deflate and `.swf` flash file issues: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=mod+defalte+defaults&oq=mod+defalte+defaults&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l5.3099j0&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=122&espv=210&psj=1&q=mod_deflate+flash+files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This directive in your web server configuration:

```
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
```

enables DEFLATE compression for all files. You don't want this - along with messing up Flash files, it's a waste of time for data which is already compressed, including most image formats. Remove it, along with all of the outdated nonsense which follows it. (Most of what you have there is workarounds for prehistoric browsers and web servers.)

Comment: Thanks, so it's safe to just remove all of that and go with the defaults now?